# Is math.random using brackets first?

Tags: javascript

In what order is this code executed.

```
                Math.floor(Math.random() * (max + 1));
```

Max is a variable passed through a function.

Does it add max to 1 ( Bracket first)  and then multiplies it by the value generate by Math.random() and then finally the value is passed to Math.floor?

Comment: That's how parentheses always work.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Comment: More to the point, that's the whole point of parentheses: They allow you to specify explicit grouping of operations.

Comment: FYI, `()` are parentheses, `[]` are (square) brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Just like in math, paranthesis enjoys priority and follows standard operator precedence:

1. `max + 1`
2. `Math.random()` multiplied with the result of `max + 1`
3. result of 2. above passed into `Math.floor()`